# How to overload template functions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to overload template functions in a class but with no success.

How can i overLoad template in my code.

```
class CommandInterfaceFont
{
private:
    std::map < std::string, FontParam > lookUpMap;

public:
    CommandInterfaceFont();
    friend class SumCommandInterface;

    template <typename plug , typename typeValue >
    void SetValue(plug* geom, std::string stdstrParamName, typeValue value);

};
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
template <typename plug >
void CommandInterfaceFont::SetValue(plug* geom, std::string stdstrParamName, std::string value)
{       
            geom->setText(value);       
}

template <typename plug >
void CommandInterfaceFont::SetValue(plug* geom, std::string stdstrParamName, bool value)
{   
            geom->setUseShadow(value);      
}
```

Comment: It is not overload but partial specialization that you wrote. and partial specialization on function(method) is disallowed.

Comment: Syntax for partial specialisation is wrong, though... If you really want to have overloads, you need to declare them in class already (which you didn't).

Comment: You don't modify the strings, do you? So you might prefer to accept them as const references instead to avoid unnecessary copies. Have you considered accepting the `plug` parameters by reference instead of by pointer? You don't need to bother with null pointers then (you don't check for, so if being strict, you'd actually have to document that passing a null pointer is invalid/invokes undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```cpp
template <typename plug , typename typeValue >
void SetValue(plug* geom, std::string stdstrParamName, typeValue value);
```

declare the member functions like this:

```cpp
template <typename plug >
void SetValue(plug* geom, std::string stdstrParamName, std::string value);

template <typename plug >
void SetValue(plug* geom, std::string stdstrParamName, bool value);
```

If overloading is what you want. Your example looks more like [specialization](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Comment: I'd recomment to add the class context around the declarations to make more explicit where they actually need to occur.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Lehks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9298910/lehks) answer: It even is possible to have all three overloads, the one accepting bool, std::string *and* a generic one. It might not be meaningful in this very concrete use case (but you need to decide yourself), but for completeness (see it as a more general extension), I'm still going to show:

```
class CommandInterfaceFont
{
public:

    template <typename plug , typename typeValue >
    void setValue(plug* geom, std::string stdstrParamName, typeValue value)
    {
        // does something generic, whatever this would be
    }

    template <typename plug >
    void setValue(plug* geom, std::string stdstrParamName, std::string value)
    {
        // specific
    }

    template <typename plug >
    void setValue(plug* geom, std::string stdstrParamName, bool value)
    {
        // specific
    }
};
```

Key to be able to do so remains that you need to at least declare *all* of these overloads already in class scope!

Looks now, like calling `setValue(somePlug, "", false)` is ambigous. However, the boolean overload is *more specialised* and thus will be preferred according to C++ rules...